# CSS div position overlay images

Tags: css, css-float

I have stated creating a simple MVC 4 Site which can be seen here: [problem site](http://yis.azurewebsites.net/)

I would like the alternating images to appear to the right of the paragraph within the blue border.

To alternate the images I am using the authors initial JS from here: [JQuery](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
           .next('img').fadeIn()
           .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    },
      3000);
});
</script>
```

The markup from my index.cshtml is as follows:

```
<div id="intro">
    <p>
    Don't let memories fade - preserve them for generations to come.<br />
    Yorkshire Image Scanning can create perfect digital copies of your photographs, stored on DVD or USB memory stick.
    The access the digital images simply insert into a DVD player and a slideshow will start to run. 
    Alternatively, the images can be copied to your PC, iPad, smartphone etc and backed up using any normal method such as external hard disk or DVD copies or cloud storage.
    Of course, digital images are so much easier to share than old photographs. Upload them to facebook and let distant friends share your memories!
    </p>
</div>
<div class="fadein">
    <img src="~/Content/img/old_photos/1.jpg" alt="Old Photos" />
    <img src="~/Content/img/old_photos/2.jpg" alt="Old Photos" />
    <img src="~/Content/img/old_photos/3.jpg" alt="Old Photos" />
    <img src="~/Content/img/old_photos/4.jpg" alt="Old Photos" />
    <img src="~/Content/img/old_photos/5.jpg" alt="Old Photos" />
</div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
#intro {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}

.fadein { width:300px; height:300px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
```

Could anyone please advise what I need to do to move the images? It seems that unless I have the .fadin img with a position:absolute then I get to see each of the images at the same time when jQuery flicks to the next image. I don't know how to set the all images to a position relative to the previous div so that each image overlays the previous?

Comment: The answer is exactly how you described make `.fadein` position relative and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `.fadein` relative and float right and that should give you what you want.

EDIT:
Thanks to  **Ilya Streltsyn**
You'd be better off using `margin-left: auto` on your `.fadein` div. This would prevent the parent from collapsing when using floats.

Comment: Another option to move the the div to the right is to set margin-left: auto.

Comment: Actually, the margin-left would be better than floating the element since that would avoid the parent div from collapsing - I didn't think of that.

Comment: thanks folks, it works perfectly. Here's the updated CSS .fadein { position:relative; margin-left:auto; width:300px; height:300px; }
.fadein img {position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }

Answer (score 0):

Your `.fadein` solution should work with `position:relative;`