# Simple jquery slideshow relative position

Tags: jquery, css

I thought I had the answer here: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443799/css-div-position-overlay-images)

Unfortunately, although it looks great on a PC, the text gets covered by the rotating images when viewed on a phone.

My CSS is class is currently set as follows:

```
.fadein { position:relative; margin-left:auto; width:300px; height:300px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
```

The site can be viewed here: [YIS website](http://yis.azurewebsites.net/)

Could anyone please suggest if there's any CSS change I can make to prevent the pics from overwriting the text without hitting the previous problems of the next pic being drawn away from the previous.

Comment: Try media queries. You should change intro css too by media queries (width:300px, float:none), and accordingly - 'push' fadein div bellow it... maybe it will cause changes to the rest, but you will have to tweak css a little for mobiles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the content is covered if you reduce the width of any browser.

remove #intro float attribute and instead add:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

to both #intro and .fadein

what this does is displays each block as an inline block, meaning, with space they will display horizontally and when it is reduced it will wrap; however, there is one other thing that will keep this wrapping from happening properly, that is, the relative width of #intro. Now, you can keep this, but also add:

```
min-width: someWidthInReaUnits
```

This will make the text force the image div to wrap once the minimum width is hit.

Finally, you can use margins fine-tune the position of both elements as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need the intro div to bee 100% width minus the width of the image. This way it will remain fluid.

```
#intro {
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: calc(100% - 310px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do:

```
@media screen and (max-width:360px){
    #intro {
        width:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        float:none;
        height:auto;
    }
    .fadein{
        position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px;
    height:300px}
    .content-wrapper{margin:0 auto;max-width:100%}
    .featured {

        width:100%;
        float:none;
    }
    .float-left{float:none} // it seems that it will not affect view

    .float-right{float:none} // it seems that it will not affect view
}
```

Images will be placed bellow text, the rest looks pretty fine (tested in responsive design view, firefox -360px width). I have experimented with margins... when i set fixed size for #intro... (thats why margin:0 auto is left on some places)